# PhpStorm not displaying xdebug as stopped on breakpoint (docker)

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

So I have my webserver container happily running xdebug, and I have xdebug.remote_log setup so I could diagnose the issue. If I place a breakpoint on the first line phpstorm behaves as expected, it breaks, gives you the normal options. But if you allow it to continue running past that point phpstorm has the appearance that the code is timing out, it just hangs. However if I read the xdebug remote_log during this time, it reports that it has successfully hit the next breakpoint I set and is waiting there, phpstorm shows the code as executing.

Here are some screenshots of configs and such:

php.ini

[image]

settings > languages & frameworks > php > Debug

[image]

settings > languages & frameworks > php > Servers > localhost (docker) aka my only added server

[image]

Screenshot from the end of xdebugs remote_log. From the public/index.php initial breakpoint I then allowed it to run. And then here it states it broke in ListController.php which is the correct location for the next placed breakpoint. As you may have guessed from the previous image, in docker the repo is in /srv/www while on my local its in /home/myname/Development/projectName/checkout.

[image]

xdebug remote_log: https://pastebin.com/faiQqwMT

```
some code so stackoverflow will let me link the log
```

The only interesting part of my idea.log

2018-10-12 10:18:23,772 [81267328]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Argument for @NotNull parameter 'remoteFileUrl' of com/jetbrains/php/debug/xdebug/debugger/XdebugDriver.onBreak must not be null 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'remoteFileUrl' of com/jetbrains/php/debug/xdebug/debugger/XdebugDriver.onBreak must not be null
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.debugger.XdebugDriver.$$$reportNull$$$0(XdebugDriver.java)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.debugger.XdebugDriver.onBreak(XdebugDriver.java)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.debugger.XdebugDriver$4.onResponse(XdebugDriver.java:172)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.xdebug.debugger.XdebugDriver$4.onResponse(XdebugDriver.java:167)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.connection.PhpDebugConnection.handleInput(PhpDebugConnection.java:256)
    at com.jetbrains.php.debug.connection.PhpDebugConnection.lambda$startReading$2(PhpDebugConnection.java:290)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Do you have the project directories added to include path? Any reasons for that?

Comment: @Ástþór I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: on the last screenshot you have the same path listed in Project files and Include path. You shouldn't have it this way ideally. The issue (I guess) is that IDE can't find correct path mappings after the code goes into other PHP files. It would be great if you could share your xdebug.log file + illustrate your project structure (show us the files involved in debugging)

Comment: If I fill in one it fills in both. I'd guess that's the mapping is the issue too, how should it look instead? I'll take some screenshots of the issue in more detail tomorrow at work

Comment: @Ástþór added some extra detail at the bottom of the post

Comment: I would appreciate full idea.log file & xdebug.log files instead

Comment: @Ástþór added the two logs. Although not all of my idea.log because it reveals who I am and which company I work for

Comment: Thanks! That's a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622. Switch over to XDebug 2.6

Comment: @Ástþór awesome thank you, post that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: You're welcome! Copied the comment into an answer

Comment: As of PhpStorm 2018.3, though I haven't checked with that version, this issue should be fixed. I'm using 2019.1.1 now and can debug an environment with xdebug 2.7.0 with no problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622. Switching back to XDebug 2.6 should fix it.

Comment: For anyone coming into this issue in 2019, it seems that the latest version on PhpStrom (2019.1.1) fixes the issue. I was having an issue with PhpStorm locking things up when trying to debug an environment with xdebug 2.7.0, after updating PhpStorm I'm able to debug this environment with no issues. This was mentioned in the comments of the ticket linked above: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622#focus=streamItem-27-3153651.0-0

Comment: Thanks, by upgrading the PHPStrom version it is working :) @